# Python encoding error adding to mysql table

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, encoding

I have the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE language (
    language varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (language)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

I have the following code to add a language to a database

```
self.cursor.execute("""INSERT IGNORE INTO language (language)  
                    VALUES (%s)""", 
                   (["PORTUGUÊS".encode('utf-8')]))
self.conn.commit()
```

The table and db are encoded for utf8_bin. The problem is... If the word doesn't exist it adds without any trouble. If it exists the following error is given;

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xca' in position 24: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Have been scratching my head for hours

Comment: Remove the encode, that is what is causing your error

Comment: @Padraic already did, nothing changes

Comment: Sorry yes, I presume you are using python3?

Comment: @Padraic no, I'm using python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

1st or 2nd line in source code (to have literals in the code utf8-encoded):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

If you need more Python/utf8 tips:
http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python

Comment: I have that, should have mentioned though

Comment: Hmmm... `CA` is the hex for the latin1 encoding for `Ê`.  What happens if you remove the `.encode(...)` call?

Comment: No changes whatsoever :\